# How to nest collection routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, separation-of-concerns, nested-resources, nested-routes

I use the following routes configuration in a Rails 3 application.

```
# config/routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :products do
    get 'statistics', on: :collection, controller: "statistics", action: "index"
  end

end
```

The `StatisticController` has two simple methods:

```
# app/controllers/statistics_controller.rb
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @statistics = Statistic.chronologic
    render json: @statistics
  end

  def latest
    @statistic = Statistic.latest
    render json: @statistic
  end

end
```

This generates the URL `/products/statistics` which is successfully handled by the `StatisticsController`.

How can I define a route which leads to the following URL: `/products/statistics/latest`?

---

Optional: I tried to put the working definition into a [concern](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) but it fails with the error message:

`undefined method 'concern' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do it by two ways.

method 1:

```
  resources :products do
    get 'statistics', on: :collection, controller: "statistics", action: "index"
    get 'statistics/latest', on: :collection, controller: "statistics", action: "latest"
  end
```

method 2, if you have many routes in `products`, you should use it for better organized routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :products do
    resources 'statistics', only: ['index'] do
      collection do
        get 'latest'
      end
    end
  end

end
```

and put your `StatisticsController` in a namespace:

```
# app/controllers/products/statistics_controller.rb
class Products::StatisticsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @statistics = Statistic.chronologic
    render json: @statistics
  end

  def latest
    @statistic = Statistic.latest
    render json: @statistic
  end

end
```

Comment: Method 1 configures the **correct routes** pointing to: `statistics#index` and `statistics#latest`. Method 2 generates routes **incorrectly** pointing to: `products/statistics#index` and `products/statistics#latest`. I also set the namespace.

Comment: Hi, method 2 is just pointing to products/statistics#index, because it has a namespace :) If you persist to use statistics#index, just use method 1.

Comment: I missed to move the controller into the subdirectory `products`. However, namespacing the controller to `Products` hinders me from **re-using the `StatisticsController`** for other classes such as `Articles` and `articles/statistics` and so on ...