# RoR Magazine specific category routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, custom-routes

I would like to create routes on RoR for a media website with different sections of articles (`ecology`, `legal`, `economy`, etc...)

I would like my url goes like this

```
root/magazine/ecology/name-of-articles
```

(nothing corresponding on rails routing/rails guide, nested and collection routes don't fit for me I think)

here is my try:

```
get 'magazine/ecology/name-of-article', to: 'articles#name_of_article'
views: folders articles => magazine => ecology => file: name_of_article
controller: articles
```

But it's not working ...answer from rails below
Thx for your help

> ActionController::UnknownFormat at
>   /magazine/actualite-juridique/legislation-ce-qui-change-en-2017
>   ArticlesController#legislation_2017 is missing a template for this
>   request format and variant.
>
> request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []
>
> NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond
>   with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in
>   a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a
>   template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If
>   you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an
>   XHR or API request. Give it a shot.

Comment: do you save the `kind` (ecology, legal, economy, etc...) of article in your `articles` model?

Comment: No my idea was to avoid creating models for each category (belongs to & association). I am trying with collection routes but its working only in second level and not third level.

Comment: Here is my code <pre> resources :magazine, only: [ :index ] do
    collection do
      get 'actualite-juridique', to: 'magazine#home_actualite_juridique' do
        collection do
          get 'legislation_2017', to: 'magazine#legislation_2017'
        end
      end
    end
  end <code>

Comment: so, you plan to add a new `route` for every new release?

Comment: exactly ! the code I did work on a second level (root/magazine/actualite-juridique) but not on a third level (root/magazine/actualite-juridique/article-on-subject). I m wondering if I can use nested collection routes ?

Comment: Maybe I ve foudn something usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244453/how-to-nest-collection-routes

Comment: in that case, u will have to add endless number of actions for each article. I don't think that's feasible/recommended.

Comment: I prefer this way (more work but ability to custom) Look in the post above with collections. Tks anyway for you help Farhan Memon

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't seek a solution and what you trying to do as discussed in the comments, I don't at all recommend that. I would like to suggest a better method. Take it if you like it.

Run a migration add a column to your `articles` model which will save the name of `section` it belongs to.
Then, your routes:

```
get 'magazine/:section/:name' => 'articles#name_of_article' , as: 'sectioned_article'
```

In your controller:

```
def name_of_article
  @article = Article.where("section iLike '%#{params[:section]}% AND name iLike '%#{params[:name]}%'").first
end
```

This way, you can create as many sections/articles you want without code changes.
It also gives you customisation option and also reduces your work to great extent which you are ready to do [but now you can utilize that time partying ;)].